# Can't find the Jordan form of this 3x3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & -2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

and need to find its Jordan canonical form.  I can find that the only eigenvalue is 1 with algebraic multiplicity 3, and I can find two independent eigenvectors,

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\qquad \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

I am told that to find a generalized eigenvector I need to solve

$$A\vec{x} = \vec\xi$$

where $\vec\xi$ is an eigenvector.  However, when I try to solve in this case,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & -2 & 1 \\
-1 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

I find that there is no solution, and likewise for the other eigenvector.

I've also seen instruction that to find the generalized eigenvector you can solve $(A-\lambda I)^2\vec x=\vec0$ which in this case is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & -2 & 1 \\
-1 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^2\vec{x} = \vec{0}$$

But the square of this matrix is the zero matrix.  I thought perhaps that means I can select any independent vector I want, but when I select $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ I find that the resulting transformation matrix does not produce a matrix in Jordan form.  That is to say, with

$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

If I compute $J=T^{-1}AT$ I get

$$J = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Since that's not in Jordan form, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Compare with other questions, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314114/how-to-turn-this-matrix-to-jordan-normal-form?rq=1).

Comment: Actually, you should be finding that the solution to $A\vec x=\vec\xi$ is $\vec\xi$, since the only eigenvalue is $1$. Are you sure that’s the correct equation for finding generalized eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have found that $(A-\lambda I)^2=0$, you can pick any vector $x_1$ that is not en eigenvector, e.g. as you suggested $x_1=(0,0,1)^T$. After that, you construct the corresponding eigenvector as $x_2=(A-\lambda I)x_1=(-1,1,1)^T$. Next, you pick an eigenvector that is linearly independent with $x_1$ and $x_2$ (independent with $x_2$ is enough), e.g. $x_3=(1,0,1)^T$. Now make $T=[x_1\ x_2\ x_3]$.

As to your first approach, it is not guaranteed that you can solve $(A-\lambda I)x=\xi$ for *any* eigenvector $\xi$, it is only possible to solve the system for *some* $\xi$. It means that you need to solve
$$
(A-\lambda I)x=t\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $t,s$. Since the last two equations are dependent, you get easily that the RHS must be the same, i.e. $s=t+2s$ etc.

Comment: Every time I do this, with different choices of $x_1,x_2,x_3$, or with exactly your numbers, I still get that $T^{-1}AT$ comes out just slightly off from a Jordan form.

Comment: @Addem Sorry, I think you get the transpose of $J$. It is because I have made the wrong order, it should be $T=[x_2\ x_1\ x_3]$, i.e. $$T=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Cool, I'll test this out in a minute.  Hopefully a quick follow-up: For a general matrix with known eigenvalues and generalized eigenvalues, how do you know which order is correct?

Comment: Er, I meant eigenvectors but I'm sure that was clear.

Comment: @Addem The complete algorithm is quite involved, but if you know that every Jordan block corresponds to a chain $$0\leftarrow w_0\leftarrow w_1\leftarrow\ldots\leftarrow w_k$$ where each $\leftarrow$ is the mapping $A-\lambda I$ (i.e. $w_0$ is the eigenvector) then the transformation matrix contains the vectors $[\ldots w_0\ w_1\ \ldots\ w_k\ldots]$ in this order.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only eigenvalue is $1$ and it has multiplicity $3$, you know that the Jordan normal form is one of a short list:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\hspace{1cm}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\hspace{0.5cm}\text{or}\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Call these $A_1,A_2$, and $A_3$. As you say, we can determine the size of the Jordan blocks by looking at $\dim\ker(A-I)$, where $I$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. Notice that

$$A-I=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
from which, by row operations for example, we see $\dim\ker(A-I)=2$. This means that $A$ has two Jordan blocks, so we have ruled out $A_1$. Next, compute $\dim\ker(A-I)^2$. Actually, $(A-I)^2$ is the $0$ matrix, so $\dim\ker(A-I)^2=3$. This tells us that the biggest Jordan block has rank $2$, so the correct answer is $A_2$.

---

As confirmation, Mathematica returns the Jordan normal form
$$J=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
with the conjugating matrix as
$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
That is, $T^{-1}AT=J$.

---

Comment: How do we know it's not $J=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$?  And why use the middle column as $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$?  This solution doesn't seem like you could generalize it to finding the answer in other contexts, if there is no principle way that we're generating $T$--unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The $J$ you gave is similar to the one I wrote, so thats just a matter of convention. This solution generalizes to find the Jordan normal form of a matrix, but you're right that I didn't compute $T$ by myself.

Comment: right, it's similar, but how do you know what to construct? If I  don't know how to get the things you got, then all I know is the solution to this problem, not how to solve all such problems.

Comment: “This means that $A$ has two Jordan blocks” immediately rules out $A_3$ as well.